# Increasing memory usage from CheckedListBox -- Is this normal?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a C# tool to assist me in analyzing log files for my work, and I'm using Winforms to create the interface. I've noticed that every time I check or un-check an item in a `CheckedListBox`, the memory usage of my program jumps a bit (a few hundred kilobytes at most). Repeatedly checking and unchecking items causes the program to climb in memory usage from something like 50MB to 150MB, and it just keeps rising from there.

I've monitored the memory usage through Visual Studio's profiling tools, dotMemory, and Task Manager. Each confirms that the memory is climbing, but I'm not sure why.

Here's dotMemory:

[image]

I am unable to locate the "leak" in my code, so I tested checking / unchecking a blank Winform with a number of identical items in a `CheckedListBox` and noticed that the **memory climbs similarly** (albeit to a lesser degree)!

I'm obviously a novice when it comes to C# and memory management. I'm not sure whether this is something that I should be worried about, or whether I'm being impatient with the garbage collector. Though the problem appears to be un-managed memory...

The full <strike>spaghetti</strike> source is [here](https://github.com/Naught0/LogMeIn-Log-Analyzer) if you're at all interested.

Comment: Does the leaked memory get freed if you close the form containing the CheckedListBox?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure of the best way to test this! I _believe_ so, but that's based on Task Manager, which I've heard is unreliable.

Comment: enable on task manager, object identifiers column and see how many objects the application have created

Comment: 1.3 MB is peanuts, you're not close to even filling gen#0.  Hunting down *unmanaged* memory usage is never that simple, bitmaps are the usual cause but I don't see any.  The more obvious candidate is the Scintilla library wrapper, it is unmanaged code with a friendly C# interface.  If you keep adding lines but never remove any then you'll inevitably consume more and more memory.

Comment: @HansPassant Peanuts indeed! The total memory, though, is more worrying. I'm simply re-assigning the `Scintilla.Text` variable to change displayed text, but I may have some other nefarious code lying around with it... I'll check it out

Comment: @HansPassant I did just find something of interest in [this Github issue](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/254#issuecomment-227621143). He says every time you call `get` on `Scintilla.Text`, it allocates a new string. In order to do a lot of operations I reference `Scintilla.Text`. Could this be it?

Comment: No, you only use 1.3 MB

Comment: Somewhat interesting update: I used FastColoredTextBox as a drop-in replacement to ScintillaNET and a similar climb in unmanaged memory happened. I'm going to test with a ListBox or something else built-in to see whether that exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

On Code:

```
CheckListItem toAdd = CountMatches(item, splitFileContents);
    if (toAdd.Display != string.Empty)
        checkedListBoxMore.Items.Add(CountMatches(item, splitFileContents));
```

You have created `toAdd` object, but before don't add to check list, you create more one.
Use same object to add on check list:

```
CheckListItem toAdd = CountMatches(item, splitFileContents);
    if (toAdd.Display != string.Empty)
        checkedListBoxMore.Items.Add(toAdd);
```

You can also free the object from memory, using `Dispose` method, on `ControlRemoved` event:

```
checkedListBoxMore.ControlRemoved += (ss, ee) => {
            ee.Control.Dispose();
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll see whether that helps. Out of curiosity, must users typically manually `Dispose()` events like this? Will the program just increase in memory infinitely without doing this? Also, would I include this bit of code in the constructor for the form? What's the best practice there? (Sorry for the slew of questions)

Comment: Usually using () blocks are used, at the end of them the object is discarded, but only used within the specific block. In the case of controls, GarbageCollector does this work, but only when the object will no longer be used (no reference to it anymore). In your case, since there are many controls in a loop, it is best to release them soon or memory will increase until an exception is raised. You can put in the constructor or associate the event in the visual studio design editor (Properties> Events> etc ..)

Comment: I'm coming from Python, so the `using()` block reminds me of `with()`! 
I've added your suggestion from the designer on the `ControlRemoved` event, saying `e.Control.Dispose()` in the function, but the same memory usage climb is occurring. However, there are a lot more GC events showing in Process Memory portion of Visual Studio...https://i.imgur.com/5LyB8MZ.png

I also removed the duplicate `toAdd` variable to no avail.

I'm going to check to see whether I'm misusing the Scintilla control per Hans' comment and report back!